# THREE.js: TrackballControls work, but OrbitControls don't

Tags: three.js, mouse

I tried adding `TrackballControls` to my scene and it works flawlessly.
However, I realized `OrbitControls` would suit my needs better. But I can't get it to work.

This is the code I use to initialize `TrackballControls`:

```
this.mouseControls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, self.renderer.domElement );
this.mouseControls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

I call the `mouseControls.update()` function in the general update function, of course.

As I understand, OrbitControls should be pretty much the same. But if I simply change `THREE.TrackballControls` to `THREE.OrbitControls` and leave everything else as it was, I get an exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener'
```

I tried Googling, but it didn't help.

Comment: check the versions, are both trackball controls and OrbitControls from the same Three.js revision? If you are on R66, download the up to date OrbitControls.js version. Maybe this helps

Comment: @GuyGood hadn't thought of that. That was the culprit. Well, I guess that's what I get for blindly copy-pasting files from previous projects.

Thanks!

Comment: np, made the same mistake and many others too, i guess. :D